# VB.Net Radian to Degree conversion

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I got a bit of problem with my homework. I have to create a program using VB.Net to calculate root of a function using MOSS (Method of Successive Substitution). The function is (5+sin(x))/2 and the initial value of x is 2. Now on the first iteration the value of  Xn+1  must be 2.52 (which is in Degree), the problem is VB.Net's math method is in Radian with the answer of 2.95. How can I convert radian value of 2.95 to degree value of 2.52? I have tried the formula degree=radian*180/PI but it results in a different answer. This is my code that displays the answer in radian (2.95):

```
Dim d As Decimal = Math.Sin(2)
        d = (5 + d) / 2
```

UPDATE: Solved!

```
 Dim d As Decimal = Math.Sin(2 / (180 / Math.PI))
        d = (d + 5) / 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are doing the conversion at the right place.

It should be

```
    Dim d As Decimal = Math.Sin(2 / (180 / Math.PI))
    d = (5 + d) / 2
```